# Xamarin Forms MVVM (Prism) with Media.Plugin - How to get a taken picture from device Camera

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
How to take a picture by the camera and show in display before saving data.....
```

on Page..

```
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageTakeFile2.source}" Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
```

In the ViewModel..

```
private MediaFile _photo;
 _photo = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
        { Directory = "Sample", Name = "test.jpg", PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight, MaxWidthHeight = imageSize });


ImageTakeFile2.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
     {
         var stream = _photo.GetStream();
         return stream;
     });
```

Comment: I am not sure what your question is!

Comment: sir, I want to add a new employee profile with a camera picture and display in image view before saving into database... I have only issue while displaying image in image box.

Comment: So how do you have the Image instance in your ViewModel

Comment: I have ImageTakeFile2 Image type.  ImageTakeFile2.soure wana to show in Image box

Comment: Okay I am not sure what the type of `ImageTakeFile2` object is but anyway the property `Source`  and the binding `source` would be different because of the casing so the Binding should look like `"{Binding ImageTakeFile2.Source}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!...

```
<Image Source="{Binding Img}"/>
```

In ViewModel...

```
  public ImageSource Img 
    {
        get { return _img; }
        set { _img = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Img");
        }
    }  
  private MediaFile _photo; { get; set; }                                
  Img = ImageSource.FromFile(_photo.Path);
```

Comment: That's ok also. Depends on your viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
ImageTakeFile2.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(_photo.Path);
```

.Source must be declared as ImageSource